# D8 - Using Composer to download git repo

Tags: composer

I want to download my libraries (/libraries) via composer.

Content of my composer.json:

```
 "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
    {
        "type": "github",
        "url": "https://github.com/w8tcha/CKEditor-CodeMirror-Plugin.git"
    }
]
```

I call `composer require "w8tcha/CKEditor-CodeMirror-Plugin":"*"`

which tells me

```
Error -  The requested package w8tcha/ckeditor-codemirror-plugin could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per @igorw's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954051/use-php-composer-to-clone-git-repo/12957929#12957929)

```
{
        "repositories": [
            {
                "url": "https://github.com/w8tcha/CKEditor-CodeMirror-Plugin/blob/master/composer.json",
                "type": "git"
            }
        ],
        "require": {
            "ckeditor-codemirror-plugin": "~1.17.2"
        }

}
```

Then type

> composer require "ckeditor-codemirror-plugin":"1.17.2"

Comment: Sorry I cant copy the error message in here... stackexchange doesnt allow me. Seems that the repo cannot be found. which is weird.